# Java Reading/Writing file changes characters?

Tags: java

I have a piece of code like this:

```
data = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(strFileName))); 
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(filename);
out.println(data);
```

When it writes...it's changing the quotation marks(and probably other stuff -- to what seems like gobbledy-gook. Maybe this is unsigned int stuff or something?

Here's the original:
“4 hours TILL FULL MOON”

It changed to this: 
â€œ4 hours TILL FULL MOONâ€?

I should say there are other quotations in the file that didn't change...but several did(I know single quotes had a similar issue).

Comment: If your file contains `“` and `”`, then the file is likely encoded in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), but your code is processing the file using the default character set, most likely [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1). Change your code to use the correct character set encoding. See [`java utf-8 file encoding`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+utf-8+file+encoding)

Answer (score 2):

change encoding explicitly through `PrintWriter` constructor, by default java might be using `UTF-8`

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("filename", "ISO-8859-1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(filename);
```

to

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(filename, "ISO-8859-1");
```

because printwriter by default will not use ISO-8859-1 encoding.